# I've tried to make autorole with python and my bot, but unsuccesfully, can you help me?

Tags: python, discord

The problém is, that i have the code correctly, but its not working with new discord rules.

I am working on Python 3.6.5, Windows 10. I was already making some codes for my bots, but the entire system changed, you can use change_presence, you have to use set_activity, etc.

```
  @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_role("Engineer")
    async def addrole(ctx):
        member = ctx.message.author
        role = get(member.server.roles, name="Minilord")
        await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

I hope that you know how the code should be working now

Ty guys, but now there is an error like this

````
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 860, in invoke
   await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 698, in invoke
   await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 72, in wrapped
   raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'```
````

Comment: "_I hope that you know how the code should be working now_" It's unclear from the question what your code is intended to do. If you're getting any errors, include them in your question. I suggest giving [Migrating to v1.0 – discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html) a good read, if you haven't done so already. (Just from a quick glance, `pass_context=True` has been deprecated, so that could be removed.)

Comment: my code should add a specific role ive created before to a member. and what should i put there if i remove pass context true?

Comment: This change is covered in detail in the link I previously sent (specifically, in [this subsection](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#context-changes)). Again, please give it a good read. The doc should solve most, if not all, "not working with new discord rules" issues.

Comment: The last line should probably be `await member.add_roles(role)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fifth line is faulty, it should be `role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Minilord")`.